# Cuda GPU compile, I think it is not using GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu

I try to learn CUDA. It's so similar C.
I try to run some code in my GPU.
But I think it is not fast and I think it is about my code.
I guess only my  `__global__ void func(ull* num1, ull* num2, ull* sum)` is working on GPU.
This is what I want. But It is not fast. What should I do.

```cpp
typedef uint64_t ull;

#define E1 1
#define E2 5000000000000000

__global__ void func(ull* num1, ull* num2, ull* sum)
{
    for (ull i = *num1; i <= *num2; i++)
    {
        sum[0] += i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ull n1 = E1;
    ull n2 = E2;
    ull sum = 0;

    ull* d_n1;
    ull* d_n2;
    ull* d_sum;

    cudaMalloc(&d_n1, sizeof(ull));
    cudaMalloc(&d_n2, sizeof(ull));
    cudaMalloc(&d_sum, sizeof(ull));

    cudaMemcpy(d_n1, &n1, sizeof(ull), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_n2, &n2, sizeof(ull), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_sum, &sum, sizeof(ull), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    func <<<1,1000>>> (d_n1, d_n2, d_sum);

    cudaMemcpy(&sum, d_sum, sizeof(ull), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    cudaFree(d_n1);
    cudaFree(d_n2);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

GPUs and CUDA are not "make programs fast magically" technology. You'll have to parallelize your algorithms and work with multiple threads.

At the moment your code will perform the *very same* operations, on the *very same* memory on all involved cores, which not only wastes resources, but also is tripping over its own feet since all those concurrent memory addresses to the same location will impair each other.

Also summing an array is something that's not "trivial" to do in parallel. You'll have to split and merge the task, working up recursively.

You really, absolutely must learn how GPUs work and how to make use of what they bring to the table.

Comment: Thank you but you're so rude :'(

Comment: @MuhammedYaşar: Sorry, but what else other than honestly can I offer? The solution to your problem is to properly prallelize your summing operation. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. As for parallel sum on GPUs, plenty of stuff has been written on that. I mean, if I type "GPU parallel sum" into Google I get this: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-vi-gpu-computing/chapter-39-parallel-prefix-sum-scan-cuda

Comment: Thanks you are rigth :)